# Node.js /JavaScript - Java's Jackson equivalent

Tags: javascript, java, json, node.js, jackson

Is there a technique or module I can use in my node project that will take in JSON from a rest API and store it in some sort of readable object?

I understand currently that when I get data from a REST API, express's body parser will store it as a JSON object for me and I can traverse the tree from there, my issue is what if a contributor to my project has no idea what the JSON from the REST API looks like.

In Java you can tell since JACKSON will map it to a Java bean, in JavaScript I feel like you are going in blindly. If a contributor is using sublime and they don't have a debugger how should they figure out what the JSON object looks like?

Comment: Can you go into more detail by what you mean by "readable object"? I think the JSON specification was designed to be readable by humans and should be easily parseable by machines as well. Perhaps your JSON is minified making it harder to read?

Comment: I suggest using [Typescript interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

Answer (score 2):

In nodejs, you can use `express-jsonschema` package to validate the incoming json to rest endpoints. If the json is not compliant with schema, you can respond with bad request error ( http status 400).

Please look more about this package on package manager (npmjs.com).

Answer (score 0):

AJV package can be used to validate the incoming JSON.That is best in performance

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv